# how to get ref's in reusable component in react js

Tags: reactjs, ref

Hi guys I am new bee to react js . I have reusable component which has ref property .When I pass **_ref** props value to **Reusablecomponent** . I don't get proper `ref` value. I mocked the same in below code (What value i have received in Reusable component).

**Reusable component**

```
     class A extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
        super(props)
        ...
        }
    componentDidMount() {
//TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined
        if (this.props._ref && !this.props._ref.disabled) {
            this.props._ref.current.focus();
            this.props._ref.current.select();
        }
     }
        render(){

        //If I console.log of this.props._ref . 
        //I got function like function (input) { return this2.firstField  = input  }
        //If i try to do any focus () or select() method I got an error with msg 
        // Focus or select method is not a function 

        return(
        <div>
        <input  type="text" ref={this.props._ref} value = {this.props.value}  />
        </div>
        )
        }
```

**Own component**

```
class own extends React {
constructor(props){
super(props);
}

handleChange = () => {
//I need to check the cursor . where its reside if the cursor in first input field I need to disable the button like I have requirement . 
}

render(){

return(
<A value = {"userName"} _ref = {input => this.firstField = input }/>
)

}
}
```

As I mentioned my scenario , I dont have any clue how to do this . Am i expected in `handleChange` method is possible ? . Please guide me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the ReactJs Docs:

> When a ref is passed to an element in render, a reference to the node
>   becomes accessible at the **current** attribute of the ref.

Try using `this.props._ref.current.focus()`

Comment: I have edited the question . still I am getting undefined value in reusable component . Please correct me am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: @SakthiSureshAnand Create a ref in your class Own like this.firstField=React.createRef(), Pass the ref as _ref={this.firstField}, use the ref props as this.props._ref.current.focus() and now the input field gets focused and selected. Good to go!

Comment: yeah I missed the React.createRef() in my own component . I have added it works fine now . I can access the values in Reusable components .

Comment: Accepted @kreysix

Comment: one small confusion how can I access or get to the know information of currently cursor reside in my `own component` . As of now I am passing `_ref` as props to my `reusable component` it has info but if i need those in my own component what should I do ? could you please give some suggestions

Comment: @SakthiSureshAnand use ```this.props._refs.current.value``` to get the current value

Comment: should i use my own component this.props._refs.current.value ?

Comment: I tried in my own component as you mentioned but it failed with undefined error . Actually I need the cursor info in both component (own and reusable) . So I did work around created `onFocus` method for every input filed then I `setState` the string whenever cursor comes any input field like first , second fileds etc., .using that state var value I found currently cursor is where in my screen either first , second or third . please provide any other way to access the refs in own component too I am also exploring it ,.;)